# Cumulative sum over a period of time

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a Date column and some other columns. I need to calculate how many occurrences I have every day and create a cumulative sum. For example:

```
Date   

2017-02-14 11:00:06          
2017-02-14 14:10:31          
2017-02-15 01:35:02                    
2017-02-18 21:10:25          
2017-02-18 22:15:32                   
2017-02-18 23:13:55          
2017-02-19 19:43:44
...
```

should become:

```
Date        Cum_Counts          
2017-02-14    2          
2017-02-15    3          
2017-02-18    6          
2017-02-19    7
```

I know that I can use `df['Date'].groupby(df['Date'].dt.day).count()` and get the counts per day. But I want:

1. the cumulative counts
2. the date itself in the first column (as in the example above).

Is there a way to do this directly with groupby?

Comment: `df['Date'].dt.normalize().value_counts().sort_index().cumsum()`

Answer (score 3):

```
df['Date'].groupby(df['Date'].dt.day).count().cumsum()
```